# Hide all success as well as error message message after some interval

Tags: magento2, success-message

I want to hide all success messages after some interval. I have added following code in **messages.js** but it will not work on Add to cart success message. In short it will not working on messages which come from Ajax call.

```
  ...
  ....
 $.cookieStorage.set('mage-messages', '');
        setTimeout(function() {
            $(".messages").hide('blind', {}, 500)
        }, 5000);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS instead of script.

```
.success {
    -webkit-animation: cssAnimation 5s forwards; 
    animation: cssAnimation 5s forwards;
}

@keyframes cssAnimation {
    0%   {opacity: 1;}
    90%  {opacity: 1;}
    100% {opacity: 0;}
}

@-webkit-keyframes cssAnimation {
    0%   {opacity: 1;}
    90%  {opacity: 1;}
    100% {opacity: 0;}
}
```

Its work for me.

Answer (score -1):

Try the following way:

**File:** Vendor/Module/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js

```
var config = {
    "map": {
        "*": {
            "Magento_Theme/js/view/messages": "Vendor_Module/js/view/messages",
        }
    }
}
```

**File:** Vendor/Module/view/frontend/web/js/view/messages.js

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'uiComponent',
    'underscore',
    'Magento_Customer/js/customer-data',
    'jquery/jquery-storageapi'
], function ($, Component, _, customerData) {
    'use strict';

    return Component.extend({
        defaults: {
            cookieMessages: [],
            messages: []
        },

        /** @inheritdoc */
        initialize: function () {
            this._super();

            this.cookieMessages = $.cookieStorage.get('mage-messages');
            this.messages = customerData.get('messages').extend({
                disposableCustomerData: 'messages'
            });

            if (!_.isEmpty(this.messages().messages)) {
                customerData.set('messages', {});
            }

            $.cookieStorage.set('mage-messages', '');
            setTimeout(function() {
                $(".messages").hide('blind', {}, 500)
            }, 5000);
        }
    });
});
```

Now, clear cache, deploy static content and check again.

Comment: I have already applied this way but add to cart success message not showing.

Comment: I have also tried this code but not working